# Nginx still showing default index on subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have a problem on my Virtual Private Server : I already configured a "main" website which works fine, but I recently tried to create a sub domain and I am going to the "Welcome to nginx" every time I try to reach it. Here are my configuration files :

**sub.domain.com (in /etc/nginx/sites-available)**

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;
        root /home/user/www/sub;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/html;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

**Nginx.conf** (but should be good considering that it works for domain.com)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**And the file system at /home/user/**

```
        ---- domain.com ... (more files)
        |
user --- 
        |           --- index.php
        ----sub --- --- addFile.php
                    --- files (empty)
                    --- data.xml
                    --- data.dtd
```

I don't know a lot about nginx config files I just copied the default one and modified the server name and the path, but this file seems to be okay so I'm still wondering why is this not working. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

the active nginx configurations are made with symbolic links from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/vhost.conf`  to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/vhost.conf  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

in sites-enabled you have a default active, that shows the nginx index (Welcome to nginx).

> If you want delete it.

I recomend you to change your php-fpm pool to work for port

```
vim /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

and change the line:
`listen = /run/php/php-fpm.sock` for `listen = 127.0.0.1:9001` (or other port)

and restart the fpm, `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart`

if you do a `netstat -plnt` it will show you the php-fpm working in port.

```
root@server# netstat -plnt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15230/php-fpm.conf)
```

and change your vhost in this way:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;
        root /home/user/www/sub;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args; #try with this
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9003; #your fpm port
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k; 
                fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain__access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain_error.log;
}#End server Block
```

When you have the new active configuration (symbolic link) on `/etc/.../sites-enabled/`
do

```
nginx -t
```

to run a test to see if the nginx configuration is good.

```
root@server:# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

If this is not working, check the log of the application and the nginx error log.

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
/var/log/nginx/subdomain_error.log
```

(When the things are not working is where your sysadmin magic should come out)

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, first thanks for your answer. I followed everything you said plus renamed /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default in default.old, but my problem is still here. There are no logs. Do you have another idea ?